# Como Deserializar un objeto en Json que tiene otro objeto adentro en .net?

Tags: c#, json, poo, .net, deserialize

Cordial saludo...

Estoy intentando realizar lo siguiente en .net:

Consumir un .json desde: https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0

Y eso me retorna una lista de atributos del siguiente tipo:

"departureStation":"XXX","arrivalStation":"XXX","flightCarrier":"XX","flightNumber":"XXXX","price":XXX

Tengo 2 clases:

1 -> Transport(FlightCarrier, FlightNumber)
2 -> Flight(Transport,Origin,Destination, Price)

- Flight contiene a la clase transport

Lo que yo quiero es saber como hago para consumir el Json y que todos los objetos se queden en `List<Flight>`

La idea que yo tengo es recorrer el json con un for y crear los objetos manualmente... Pero no se sí es lo correcto y existe otra forma... Soy programador Python y apenas estoy aprendiendo .NET

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

string FlyURLsData = "https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0";
HttpClient client;
client = new HttpClient();
using var httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(FlyURLsData, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
string jsonStr = "";
jsonStr = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jsonObj = JsonNode.Parse(jsonStr);
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jsonObj);

//Aqui hay que mapear


public class Flight
{
    public Transport Transport { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Flight(Transport Transport, string Origin, string Destination, double Price)
    {
        this.Transport = Transport;
        this.Origin = Origin;
        this.Destination = Destination;
        this.Price = Price;
    }


}


public class Transport
{

    public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

    public Transport()
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sería que crearas una clase que refleje fielmente el JSON, algo como esto:

```
public class FlightsDTO
{
    public string DepartureStation { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalStation { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

    public Flight ToFlight()
    {
        return new Flight(new Transport()
        {
            FlightCarrier = FlightCarrier,
            FlightNumber = FlightNumber,
        }, DepartureStation, ArrivalStation, Price);
    }
        
}
```

En esta clase además incluimos una función que nos retorne `Flight` que sería el tipo de objeto que estas buscando.

Opcionalmente podrías crear una extensión para convertir una lista del tipo `List<FlightsDTO>` a `List<Flight>`

Algo así:

```
public static class ExtencionesList
{
    public static IEnumerable<Flight> TotFlights(this List<FlightsDTO> vuelos)
    {
        foreach (var v in vuelos)
            yield return v.ToFlight();
    }
}
```

Entonces tu código completo quedaría de esta manera:

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string FlyURLsData = "https://recruiting-api.newshore.es/api/flights/0";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var Flights = (await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<FlightsDTO>>(FlyURLsData))?.TotFlights();
    }
}
public static class ExtencionesList
{
    public static IEnumerable<Flight> TotFlights(this List<FlightsDTO> vuelos)
    {
        foreach (var v in vuelos)
            yield return v.ToFlight();
    }
}
public class FlightsDTO
{
    public string DepartureStation { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalStation { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

    public Flight ToFlight()
    {
        return new Flight(new Transport()
        {
            FlightCarrier = FlightCarrier,
            FlightNumber = FlightNumber,
        }, DepartureStation, ArrivalStation, Price);
    }
        
}
public class Flight
{
    public Transport Transport { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Flight(Transport Transport, string Origin, string Destination, double Price)
    {
        this.Transport = Transport;
        this.Origin = Origin;
        this.Destination = Destination;
        this.Price = Price;
    }
}

public class Transport
{
    public string FlightCarrier { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
}
```